# I am having some problems with transfering a javascript object to a php file and getting that object in a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I want to put 3 variables in a javascript object and transfer that object to a php file, then upload it to the database. The result is a table filled with zeroes instead of floats and empty text fields. I guess that somewhere along the way the values of that object get nullified.

For now I only want to upload the 2 coordinate variables: lat and lng using the obj object. The console confirms that the object is filled with the correct values so my guess is that the problem lies somewhere within the php, because when I open the php page it says the following:  "NULL New record created successfully".

Here is the javascript code:

```
var pressed = false;
      var markerPos;
      var clickCoords = {};
      var xx,yy;
      var x,y,descr;
      var objStr;
      var obj = new Object;
      var description;
      var map;
function getval()
      {
        description = document.getElementById("type").value;
      }
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
        map.addListener('mousemove', function(event) {
            markerPos = {lat: event.latLng.lat(), lng:event.latLng.lng()}
        });
        map.addListener('click',function()
        {
            if (pressed)
            {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: markerPos, map: map});
            Object.assign(obj,markerPos);
            console.log(markerPos.lat);
            pressed=false;
            }

        });
        objStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
        map.addListener("click",function()
        {
          console.log(obj.lat);
          console.log(obj.lng);
          console.log(obj);
        });
      }


      function upload()
      { 
        getval();
        $.ajax({
            url: "map.php",
            method: "post",
            data: {obj:objStr},
            success: function(res)
            {
              console.log(objStr);
            }
          });
      }
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "map";

$obj = isset($_POST['obj']);
$decoded = json_decode($obj,true);
var_dump($decoded);
$lat = $decoded['lat'];
$lng = $decoded['lng'];
$descr = $decoded['descr'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO mapinfo (lat,lng,descr)
VALUES ('$lat','$lng','$descr')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($decoded);` returns `null` check on your network tab of the browser concole what formdata passed

Comment: Use a conditional statement for this `isset($_POST['obj'])`, since it will always be considered as being set.

Comment: Well it removed the NULL from NULL New record created successfully but the database is still empty. Still thank you for clearing up that a bit.

Comment: is it supposed to be ```if (isset($_POST['obj']));
{
    $obj = $_POST['obj'];
    $decoded = json_decode($obj,true);
    $lat = $decoded['lat'];
    $lng = $decoded['lng'];
    $descr = $decoded['descr'];
}``` because i get: Notice: Undefined index: obj in F:\webstuff\htdocs\Map\map.php on line 9